# DataView with Extjs 3

Tags: dataview, extjs3

I create a panel that show me on the left thumbnails of images and when I click on an image it shows on the right panel.
It works but i want when i open this page and without clicking on any thumb, it shows me on the right panel a defaut image (this value contain the link of the default image D.data.defaultimage)

This is my code for this panel:

```
var Pstore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
            url: 'page.php?cmd=Affich',
            method: 'POST'
        }),
        root: 'images',
        fields: [ 'name', 'url', 'thumb_url' ]
    });
    Pstore.load();

    var tpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
        '<tpl for=".">',
            '<div class="thumb-wrap" id="{name}">',
            '<center><img src="{thumb_url}" title="{name}"></center>',
                '<span>{name}</span></div>',
        '</tpl>'
    );
    tplDetail = new Ext.XTemplate(
        '<div class="details">',
            '<tpl for=".">',
                '<center><img src="{url}"></center>',       
            '</tpl>',
        '</div>'
    );

    datav = new Ext.DataView({
        autoScroll  : true,
        store       : Pstore, 
        tpl         : tpl,
        autoHeight  : false,
        multiSelect : true,
        overClass   : 'x-view-over',
        itemSelector: 'div.thumb-wrap',
        emptyText   : 'No images',
        listeners: {
            click: {
                fn: function() {
                    selNode = datav.getSelectedRecords();
                    tplDetail.overwrite(panelPreview.body, selNode[0].data);
                    panelPreview.body.fadeIn('l', {duration:0.5});
                }
            }
        }
    })

    var panelLeft = new Ext.Panel({
        id          : 'images-view',
        title       : 'Pages',
        autoScroll  : true,
        region      : 'west',
        frame       : true,
        width       : 180,
        layout      : 'fit',
        items       : datav
    });
    panelPreview = new Ext.Panel({
        title       : 'Aperçu:',
        region      : 'center',
        autoScroll  : true,
        frame       : true,
        layout      : 'fit',
        id          : 'panelDetail',
        tpl         : tplDetail
    });

    Affich = new Ext.FormPanel({
        frame       : true,
        layout      : 'border',
        bodyStyle   : 'padding:5px',
        renderTo    : 'right-bottom',
        items       : [panelLeft, panelPreview]
    });
```

Thanks for helping me

Answer (score 0):

Just a couple quick (untested) thoughts - have you tried making your panelPreview a DataView?  Then you can set its `emptyText` to the values you want.  Alternatively, Panel has a `data` config you can apply, which according to the docs is the initial set of data to load into the template.

Comment: I tried this: panelPreview = new Ext.DataView({
  store  : Pstore, 
  title  : 'Aperçu:',
  region  : 'center',
  autoScroll : true,
  frame  : true,
  layout   : 'fit',
  id   : 'panelDetail',
  overClass : 'x-view-over',
  itemSelector: 'div.thumb-wrap',
  emptyText : tplDetail2,
  tpl   : tplDetail 
 }); and tplDetail2 = new Ext.XTemplate(
  '<div class="details">',
   '<tpl for=".">',
    '<center><img src="{D.data.defaultimage}"></center>', 
   '</tpl>',    
  '</div>'
 ); but it doesn't work

Comment: I think in that case emptyText needs to be a string, not an object.  Were you able to try passing in a data config to panelPreview when it was a panel?